# What's the minimum you need to put in dialogues during a mission briefing scene in a comics?

Tags: comics, script

Because despite the amount of research I've done, I can't write a realistic scene involving a mission briefing in a military organization, I am thinking of putting the minimum amount of dialogues, but while making sure you've put in the least amount of dialogues is a good idea, what's the bare minimum such a scene should have, and what criteria should that scene fill in order to be considered correct, because I could simply start and end with "This is all for today.", but that doesn't make sense, so I was wondering if someone could guide me through this problem that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Start at the End:

Okay, so you don't realistically know how to portray a mission briefing. You can watch a war movie (especially the ones involving bombers) and copy that, but that may not work for you.

You are right, though, that eliminating it altogether won't work. Eliminating the entire briefing misses the chance to foreshadow the challenges and issues that will come up in the engagement. You have no debate or drama.

Comics often drop into a storyline abruptly, often in the middle of an action scene. You don't need to be super-clean in the logic due to the minimalist style of comics.

So skip the briefing and cut to the Q&A at the end. You can have mission details written on a board in back, if desired. Have the character express their and doubts. This addresses whatever major points you wish to mention, without going through the sausage-making of the actual briefing. You could also cut to the after part, and have the people going on the mission informally discussing amongst themselves the major points and concerns.